# Measure Time to Repair in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Hi I need to measure Time to Repair and compute the availability. I tried to use Timemeasurement but not working. here is the statechart.

Thank you

Comment: There is no statechart :) Also, welcome to SOF. "I need to do X". See this guide for how to ask good questions for AnyLogic stuff: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your state chart the best option is to record the time that you enter a state and thenonce you exit the state simply add the detla between current time and time entered to a statistics object

For example when it enters:

`timeEnterMaintenance = time();`

and then when it exists:

`timeToRepairStats.add(time() - timeEnterMaintenance);`

See example below

[image]